# Powershell script to change language and keyboard layout

Tags: windows, powershell

recently i have been trying to change language and keyboard layout by this code:

```
$languageCode = "bg-BG"
$keyboardLayout1 = "0402:00040402" 
$keyboardLayout2 = "0402:00020402"
$systemLanguages = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$systemLanguages.Add($languageCode)
$systemLanguages[1].InputMethodTips.Add($keyboardLayout1)
$systemLanguages[1].InputMethodTips.Add($keyboardLayout2)
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $systemLanguages -Force
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale $languageCode
```

The problem is that this code works only to logged user, and i want to add this language and keyboard layout to whole pc, every user. Please help :).